# How to deal with complex operation on Map in Scala

Tags: java, scala, dictionary

I am a newbie in Scala programming, but have years experience in Java.

There is a easy problem in Java that makes me struggled in Scala.

I have some records from database

```
+----+--------+--------------+------+
| id | level  | subLevel     | name |
+----+--------+--------------+------+
|  3 | level1 | subLevel1    | three|
|  4 | level2 | subLevel1    | four |
|  5 | level2 | subLevel1    | five |
+----+--------+--------------+------+
```

need to summarized to Map like this

```
{
    "level1": {
        "subLevel1": [
            {
                "id": "3",
                "name": "three"
            }
        ]
    },
    "level2": {
        "subLevel1": [
            {
                "id": "4",
                "name": "four"
            },
            {
                "id": "5",
                "name": "five"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

If in Java, maybe I could solve it this way:

```
public JSONObject centerMap() {
    List<Center> centerList = centerService.getAllCenter();

    Map<String, Map<String, List<Map<String, String>>>> centerMap = new HashMap<String, Map<String, List<Map<String, String>>>>();
    for (Center center : centerList) {
        Map<String, List<Map<String, String>>> subLevelList = centerMap.get(center.getLevel());
        if (subLevelList == null)
            subLevelList = new HashMap<String, List<Map<String, String>>>();

        List<Map<String, String>> names = subLevelList.get(center.getSubLevel());
        if (names == null)
            names = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();

        final Center c = center;
        names.add(new HashMap<String, String>(){{
            put("name", c.getName());
            put("id", String.valueOf(c.getId()));
        }});
        subLevelList.put(center.getSubLevel(), names);
        centerMap.put(center.getLevel(), subLevelList);
    }

    return JSONObject.fromObject(centerMap);
}
```

I really don't know the best way to do it in Scala.
But almost certainly not the `scala.collection.mutable.Map`

Answer (score 1):

Consider a case class such as

```
case class Entry(id: Int, level: String, subLevel: String, name: String)
```

and a collection of entries,

```
val entries = Array(
  Entry(3, "level1", "subLevel1", "three"),
  Entry(4, "level2", "subLevel1", "four"),
  Entry(5, "level2", "subLevel1", "five"))
```

Then consider grouping such values for instance by `level` and `subLevel`, as follows,

```
entries.groupBy { case Entry(id,level,subLevel,name) => (level,subLevel)}
```

Hence

```
Map((level1,subLevel1) -> Array(Entry(3,level1,subLevel1,three)), 
    (level2,subLevel1) -> Array(Entry(4,level2,subLevel1,four), 
                                Entry(5,level2,subLevel1,five)))
```

Comment: THX elm, I am trying it. Scala is truly simple as your code. Unfortunately, I am not familiar

Answer (score 1):

Building on elm's answer.

When making bigger and more permanent maps I tend to extend the pattern proposed by elm by adding a couple of different groupBy's to the same map.

```
case class LevelKey(level:String)
case class NameKey(name:String)
case class SublevelKey(level:String,subLevel:String)

val finalMap={
   val bySublevel=xs.groupBy(v=>SublevelKey(v.level,v.subLevel))
   val bylevel=xs.groupBy(v=>LevelKey(v.level))
   val byName=xs.groupBy(v=>NameKey(v.name))
   bySublevel++byLevel++byName
}
```

This way you can access the map by level, sublevel or name from the same map. Using case classes as keys makes the access code quite readable.

```
finalMap.get(LevelKey("level1"))
finalMap.get(NameKey("five"))
finalMap.get(SubLevelKey("level1", "subLevel1"))
```

The hashcode() and equals() methods of case classes are quite fast. It is my experience that this pattern can result in a speed increase compared to the pattern of using maps inside maps.